# Where to store socket connection in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

Tried two ways:

1. call `connectToServer()` from action creator within `Starter` component in `componentDidMount();` and dispatch like this:

   ```
   let socket = new Socket('ws://address/socket');

   socket.connect();

   dispatch({
     type: Constants.SESSION_SAVE_SOCKET,
     socket: socket,
   });

   const lobbyChannel = socket.channel('lobby');

   lobbyChannel.join()
   .receive('ok', () => {         
     dispatch({
       type: Constants.SESSION_LOBBYCHANNEL_RECEIVE_OK,
     });

     dispatch({
       type: Constants.SESSION_SAVE_LOBBYCHANNEL,
       lobbyChannel: lobbyChannel,
     });

   }).receive('error', (payload) => {            
       dispatch({
         type: Constants.SESSION_LOBBYCHANNEL_RECEIVE_ERROR,
       });
   });
   ```

Next I receive state by redux's mapStateToProps `connect`.
The result is component is called four times and props are empty at the result.

2. put all logic into the reducer, but the result is: component is rendered with empty props (undefined properties) and moment after I see in console logs that connection is established, but component is already rendered.

How to deal with such a issue? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I found that works is to setup your own middleware for the socket like so.

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import startWs, {wsMiddleware} from './ws.api';

function handleData(state = {data1: {}}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ApiGotData': return Object.assign({}, state, {data1: action.data});
    default: return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(handleData, applyMiddleware(wsMiddleware));

startWs(store);

export default store;
```

```js
import * as Actions from './Actions';

var socket = null;

const newData = {
  'React version': '15',
  'Project': 'Redux with socket.io',
  'currentDateTime': new Date().toLocaleString()
};

export function wsMiddleware() {
  return (next) => (action) => {
    if (socket && action.type === 'ApiGetData') {
      console.log('ApiGetData');
      socket.emit('client:GetData', {});
    } else if (socket && action.type === 'ApiSetData') {
      console.log('ApiSetData');
      socket.emit('client:SetData', action.data);
    }

    return next(action);
  };
}

export default function (store) {
  socket = new io();

  socket.on('server:GetDataDone', (data) => {
    console.log('GetDataDone');
    store.dispatch(Actions.apiGotData(data));
  });

  socket.on('server:SetDataDone', () => {
    console.log('SetDataDone');
    store.dispatch(Actions.apiGetData());
  });
  
  store.dispatch(Actions.apiSetData(newData));
}
```

The project example is ReduxSocketIO at https://github.com/jmarkstevens/ReactPatterns.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Actually I've used my first approach but instead of waiting for props within the same component I rather separate this and now it's look like: first component is responsible to connect, and result are shown in the next one.

Comment: Thanks, you really help with that!